# single line from multidimensional array, using awk

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, awk

I have a `file` which contains:

```
x1 x2 x3 x4
x5 x6 x7 x8
x9
```

Which I want:

```
x1
x2 
x3
 .
 .
```

How you do that using awk or in another ways?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk '1' RS=' ' ORS='\n' file
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
x6
x7
x8
x9
```

However personally I would do:

```
$ xargs -n1 < file
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
x6
x7
x8
x9
```

or:

```
$ grep -o '\S*' file
x1
x2
x3
x4
x5
x6
x7
x8
x9
```

Comment: And, a tongue-in-cheek `tr -d ' 0-9' < file | sed -e 's/x/x\n/g' | grep -v '^$' | cat -n | awk '{print $2, $1}' | tr -d ' '`...